# Update data in MongoDB using Mongoose and Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to update certain info in a user collection, when the user is visiting a page.

But my method doesn't work. Can anyone help to get it fixed.

```
app.get('/add-your-accommodation/apartment-type', (req, res, next) => {

  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.render('apartment-type.ejs')
  } else {
    res.render('login.ejs')
  }

  var id = req.params.id

  if(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
     User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$set: {accomtype: 'house'}},{new: true})   
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean patch method?

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to start?

Comment: It doesn't work!

Comment: @kedarsedai It doesn't matter what method you use, the update should work. Anyway, Herpryth is trying to update when the user `get`s a page (as render). The problem here is `req.params.id` is not valid. (undefined) as there is no definition of `:id` in the url (first parameter of `app.get`).

Comment: @NileshSingh How do I define correctly?

Comment: Answered below. Let know if it still fails.

Comment: @kedarsedai it's still wrong mate. Correct definition, `'/add-your-accommodation/apartment-type/:id'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `req.params.id` is undefined since there is no mention of it in the route path. You can do this,

```
app.get('/add-your-accommodation/apartment-type', (req, res) => {

  if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.render('login.ejs')
  }

  res.render('apartment-type.ejs')

  var id = req.user._id //since you're using passport (LocalStrategy)

  if(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
     User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {$set: {accomtype: 'house'}})
  }
})
```

Now when you call your API, do it like this,

```
GET /add-your-accommodation/apartment-type
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209572/discussion-on-answer-by-nilesh-singh-update-data-in-mongodb-using-mongoose-and-n).

Answer (score 0):

Try `findOneAndUpdate`. Also, use callback in your query function for getting the error or result.

```
app.get('/add-your-accommodation/apartment-type/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.render('apartment-type.ejs')
    } else {
        res.render('login.ejs')
    }
    var id = req.params.id

    if(mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
        User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}, { $set: { accomtype:'house' } },(err, result)=>{
            if (err) throw new Error(err);
            console.log(result)
            return
        })   
    }   
});
```

Comment: No, it doesn't do anything! Would you like me to send full code?

Comment: Thanks for sending me your code. I have checked and updated your query function with `findOneAndUpdate` and it works perfectly. See
https://pastebin.com/7eRBLq0z

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @kedar-sedai, when you update/change something in your DB, you should not use a `GET` request. A good practise would be to use the `PUT` method, even if you have nothing to pass in the body. It makes it easier for you and other developers to understand what your code does at a glance.

Here are 4 HTTP requests that will work in most of the use cases :

#### GET

You want to retrieve information from your DB (ex: get users, get all the apartment types...)

#### POST

You want to add information (ex: register user, add an apartment, ...), or send information using the body of the POST request (ex: login, ...)

#### PUT

You want to update a value (ex: change username, change an apartment type, ...)

#### DELETE

You simply want to delete something in your DB (ex: delete a user...)